# Install4j - How to add group box in UI form

Tags: java, install4j

I am evaluating Install4J 7.0.8. 
I wanted to add one UI form in the installer sequence.
On this form I want to have group box with title as shown in below image. 
[image]

For this I tried to used "Horizontal Group" and added border sides but it does not have provision to specify group title.

Please let me know how to add group box with title in install4J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a visual component does not exist in install4j. Use a "Horizontal separator" form component and set its "Text" property to the title in order to create groups of form components.

**Up to 7.0.8**, you can achieve it by grouping the form components in a vertical group and setting the "Initialization script" property of one of the contained "Text field" form components to

```
((JPanel)configurationObject.getParent()).setBorder(
  BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Database Detail"), 
    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8)
  )
);
```

For repeated use, extract this into a static method with the configuration object and the title as parameters on the Installer->Custom Code & Resources step.

**Starting with 7.0.9**, a "Border title" property is available that is visible below the "Border sides" property if all border sides are selected.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for your reply, Can we implement such component using custom form component. If yes, can you just point-out which interfaces need to implement.

Comment: I have implemented this feature for 7.0.9, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build.